# How properly use hibernate cache (warning The Ehcache second-level cache provider for Hibernate is deprecated)

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I'm using hibernate 5.3.7-Final with hibernate-ehcache-5.3.7.Final. In pom.xml I have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would use hibernate-cache so in hibernate.cfg.xml I have:

```
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
```

But when I started my application I see warning

```
Dez 17, 2018 6:06:43 PM 
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory <init>
WARN: HHH020100: The Ehcache second-level cache provider for Hibernate is 
deprecated.  See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12441 for details.
```

Can anyone tell me, why I see this warning and what did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
```

The above properties will wire Ehcache 2.x as the Hibernate cache and not Ehcache 3.x. As indicated in the issue linked in the warning, Ehcache 2.x is replaced by Ehcache 3 and integration as a caching provider happens through the JCache integration.

Relevant links:

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12441
- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/caching/Caching.html#caching-provider-jcache